# An algorithm for mapping one categorical distribution onto another?

Tags: python, pandas, logic, distribution, pandas-groupby

I ran into what I thought was a simple problem the other day: given a population of entities (companies, in this case), I want to project the distribution of one category onto another. For example, here are two categories:

```
     60%       40%
|----A1----|---A2---|
|---B1---|----B2----|
    40%       60%
```

In the above, category A represents 'number of employees' and category B represents 'annual sales'. Each category is a different way of slicing/bucketing the same population, so the total number of companies in 'A' categories equals the total in all 'B' categories.

Because category A1 is greater than category B1, my thinking is to get a weighted average, something like: "take 2/3 (40%/60%) of B1 and 1/3 (the remainder) of B2". In the above example, if B1 is a revenue of $1,500 and B2 of $3,000, then the average for category A1 would be $2,000 (i.e. (2/3)*$1,500 + (1/3)*$3,000). And for category A2, the revenue would simply be $3,000.

Darned if I can figure out how to code this in a way that will scale to 'n' categories and cover all situations, though. The approach I ended up using was to inflate each dataframe by the 'counts' (a solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485361/how-to-duplicate-rows-based-on-a-counter-column), btw), join using the row-index, and then take the average there. I know this boils down to a weighted-average problem, but I couldn't sort it out.

Here's my example Python/Pandas code:

```
import pandas as pd

d_A = {'Cat_A_Name': ['A1', 'A2'], 'Cat_A_Empl': [2, 5], 'Cat_A_Counts': [60, 40]}
d_B = {'Cat_B_Name': ['B1', 'B2'], 'Cat_B_Rev': [1500, 3000], 'Cat_B_Counts': [40, 60]}

df_A = pd.DataFrame(data=d_A)
df_B = pd.DataFrame(data=d_B)

# For each dataframe, do a row-expansion by count (and then drop that count column)
df_A = df_A.loc[df_A.index.repeat(df_A['Cat_A_Counts'].astype('int'))].reset_index(drop=True)
df_A.drop({'Cat_A_Counts'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
df_B = df_B.loc[df_B.index.repeat(df_B['Cat_B_Counts'].astype('int'))].reset_index(drop=True)
df_B.drop({'Cat_B_Counts'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

# Then join by index, take the average by Cat_A_Name, and drop duplicate rows
df_All = df_A.join(df_B)
df_All['Avg_Cat_B_Rev'] = df_All.groupby('Cat_A_Name')['Cat_B_Rev'].transform(pd.Series.mean)
df_All.drop_duplicates(subset='Avg_Cat_B_Rev', inplace=True)

print(df_A.head())
print(df_B.head())
print(df_All)
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this problem? 
Ideally I would be able to use a weighted average that took into account the proper category.

Comment: why join by the index? Is df_all the correct result?

Comment: Yep, that is the right answer. I didn't explain the reasoning well though - both dataframes are ordered by descending category and have the same total population (total count).